# Cant Insatll MySQL.Data from Nuget Manager

Tags: mysql, asp.net, nuget-package

I am trying to install MySQL.Web in my Project but it throw me error

Error:

```
'MySql.Data' already has a dependency defined for 'Google.Protobuf'.
```

I try both way to install it.

1. By rigth click on project -> Manage NuGet Packages
2. by writing `Install-Package MySql.Data` in Package Manager Control.

But it throw me same error at both time.

I am using Visual Studio 2012

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is your project type and target framework?

Comment: @AkshayBheda It is simple project. I just want to perform CRUD operation using MySql Database. And the framework is 4.5.

Comment: It works for .netframework 4.5.2. Visit  https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/ and view dependencies

Comment: @AkshayBheda  did you mean I have to upgrade my framework ?

Comment: Yes you need to upgrade your framework to 4.5.2. I tried to install that and it got installed in my case whereas my project type was console application and framework 4.5.2

Comment: @AkshayBheda is there any other way to use it in framework 4.5 ?

Comment: You need to install package version 6.9.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for the Framework you are using and the Dependency list.

I tried to install it Console Application in target Framework 4.5.2 and it worked.

**If you want to run in framework 4.5 then try installing package with version 6.9.12** Because the newest packages have dependencies and also they don't work in framework 4.5.2

You can check the dependencies from [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/)